# Problem editting rich text formated fields due to missing namespace in XSLT

Tags: 2011, xslt

I'm working with Tridion 2011: when a table is created in a rich text formated field of a Tridion component it works correctly, but when I save the component and I open it again for editting, if I change the content of the table some fields disappear. I guess the problem is that the namespace I set for my table (xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml") "disappears" when I save for the first time.

The xslt set in the schema used is (notice I set he xmlns in the tag "table"):

```xml
<stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
...
<template match="table | TABLE">
    <!-- Se comprueba que no existe ya el div class="C29" y se escribe el inicio de la etiqueta -->
    <choose>
        <when test="../../div[@class=&apos;C29&apos;]">
            <!-- No hacer nada -->
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;div class="C29"&gt;</text>
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
    <table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <copy-of xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" select="@cellspacing | @cellSpacing | @cellpadding | @cellPadding | @summary"></copy-of>
        <!-- Escribe el colgroup -->
        <choose xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <!-- Si tiene ya colgroup se pinta tal y como está -->
            <when test="colgroup">
                <apply-templates select="colgroup"></apply-templates>
            </when>
            <!-- sino, se escribe -->
            <otherwise>
                <colgroup xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <choose xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
                        <!-- Si tiene la etiqueta tBody -->
                        <when test="tbody">
                            <for-each select="tbody/tr">
                                <call-template name="escribir-colgroup"></call-template>
                            </for-each>
                        </when>
                        <!-- Si NO tiene la etiqueta tBody -->
                        <otherwise>
                            <for-each select="tr">
                                <call-template name="escribir-colgroup"></call-template>
                            </for-each>
                        </otherwise>
                    </choose>
                </colgroup>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
        <!-- Escribe el thead -->
        <choose xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <when test="thead">
                <apply-templates select="thead"></apply-templates>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <for-each select="//tr">
                    <choose>
                        <when test="position()=1">
                            <thead xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                                <tr>
                                    <for-each xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" select="td">
                                        <element name="th">
                                            <attribute name="scope">col</attribute>
                                            <choose>
                                                <when test="@align=&apos;left&apos;">
                                                    <attribute name="class">alignLeft</attribute>
                                                </when>
                                                <when test="@align=&apos;right&apos;">
                                                    <attribute name="class">alignRight</attribute>
                                                </when>
                                                <when test="@align=&apos;middle&apos;">
                                                    <attribute name="class">alignCenter</attribute>
                                                </when>
                                                <otherwise>
                                                    <if test="@class">
                                                        <attribute name="class">
                                                            <value-of select="@class"></value-of>
                                                        </attribute>
                                                    </if>
                                                </otherwise>
                                            </choose>
                                            <copy-of select="* | node()"></copy-of>
                                        </element>
                                    </for-each>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </when>
                    </choose>
                </for-each>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
        <!-- Escribe el tfoot -->
        <choose xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <when test="tfoot">
                <apply-templates select="tfoot"></apply-templates>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <tfoot xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></tfoot>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
        <!-- Escribe el tbody -->
        <tbody>
            <choose xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
                <!-- Si tiene la etiqueta tBody -->
                <when test="tbody">
                    <for-each select="//tr">
                        <choose>
                            <when test="position()!=1">
                                <call-template name="escribir-tbody"></call-template>
                            </when>
                        </choose>
                    </for-each>
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <for-each select="tr">
                        <call-template name="escribir-tbody"></call-template>
                    </for-each>
                </otherwise>
            </choose>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- Se comprueba que no existe ya el div class="C29" y se escribe el cierre de la etiqueta -->
    <choose>
        <when test="../../div[@class=&apos;C29&apos;]">
            <!-- No hacer nada -->
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/div&gt;</text>
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
</template>
```

This is the xml set when I build the table for the first time:

```
<div class="C29">
<table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <colgroup>
        <col xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"/>
        <col xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"/>
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" scope="col">Field 1</th>
            <th xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" scope="col">Field 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="impar">
            <td xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">Result 1</td>
            <td xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">Result 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the xml when I save the component and I open it again (the namespace is missing):

```xml
<div class="C29">
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <colgroup>
        <col xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"/>
        <col xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"/>
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" scope="col">Field 1</th>
            <th xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" scope="col">Field 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="impar">
            <td xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">Result 1</td>
            <td xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">Result 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the xml when I edit any field of the table (the xmlns "appears" again, but the boby of the table is missing):

```xml
<div class="C29">
<table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <colgroup xmlns="">
        <col xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"/>
        <col xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"/>
    </colgroup>
    <thead xmlns="">
        <tr>
            <th xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" scope="col">Field 1</th>
            <th xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" scope="col">Fieldd 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="impar"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The key is the missing xmlns in the second step: if I add it manually each time I try to edit the component the problem is solved, but I must try to find out how to solve it definitelly.

Comment: You should probably contact Customer Support about this issue. I vaguely remember some hotfixes related to this, but I could be wrong about that.